# How to see if a key is present in a map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I hav two stl maps like `map<int,int>`  and i want to compare them.. so here is the code..

```
map <int, int> a,b;
insert into a and b;
map<int,int>::iterator i;

for(i=a.begin();i!=a.end();i++){
    if(what should be here?)
         then cout << (*i).first << " also present in b" << endl;
}
```

I was hoping that something like (b[(*i).first]).exist??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`map::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) as:

```
for(i=a.begin(); i!=a.end(); i++)
{
  if( b.find(i->first) != b.end() )
       std::cout << (*i).first << " also present in b" << std::endl;
}
```

Note `i->first` and `(*i).first` are same.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`map::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/).

Answer (score 3):

This will return true if i->first (the key of the element in a pointed by i) is present in b.

```
if (b.find(i->first) != b.end())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `operator[]`, because that will create the key if it doesn't exist.  Instead, use `find`:

```
map<int,int>::const_iterator it = b.find(a->first);
if( it == b.end() )
  // NOT FOUND
```

Answer (score 1):

std::map has a function named find for finding a key in the map. See [this](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/map/find)

So the code should be :

```
if( b.find( i->first ) != b.end() )
```

Answer (score 0):

I like `b.count(i->first) > 0`.

Comment: -1: I don't because that will go through the whole map.  If its a multimap or a multiset, this is wasteful.  You only need to know that there is at least one; no need to count them all up.

Comment: What?? A) it's not a multimap, so B) no it won't go through the whole map. Sure, if it was a multimap I'd use find, but this is more concise and works fine for maps.

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886593/check-if-stdmap-contains-a-key-without-doing-insert/3886599#3886599 (which, by the way, this question is probably a dup of).

Comment: @John: Even in a multimap, it won't go through the whole map; at worst, it will iterate through the key's range.

Answer (score 0):

[map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) function

I will do as this :

```
std::map <int, int> a,b;
insert into a and b;
std::map<int,int>::iterator it = a.begin();
std::map<int,int>::iterator ite = a.end();

while (it != ite)
{
  if (b.find(it->first) != b.end())
  {
    std::cout << it->first << " also present in b" << std::endl;
  }
  ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your task for performance reasons I would suggest something like:

```
map<int,int>::iterator ia  = a.begin(), ib  = b.begin(),
                       iae = a.end()  , ibe = b.end();
while(ia != iae && ib != ibe) {
  if      (ia->first < ib->first) ia++;
  else if (ia->first > ib->first) ib++;
  else {
    cout << ia->first << " also present in b" << endl;
    ia++; ib++;
  }

}
```